# Running 64bit applications on a 32bit Raspberry Pi using Raspian

Tags: kernel, apt, package-management, raspbian, dpkg

I am looking for a way to run 64 bit applications in the 32bit Raspian OS.

I updated the kernel to the newest 64 bit kernel using:

> sudo rpi-update

Then added the 64bit flag to config.txt:

> arm_64bit=1

The kernel updated correct:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/ZendStudio $ uname -a Linux raspberrypi
>   4.19.114-v8+ #1303 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 7 15:55:30 BST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux

However I'm still unable to install 64 bit applications.

I've tried installing a few different applications and all give me the same dependency error when the package attempts the install.

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community:amd64.
(Reading database ... 166988 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community:amd64 (8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:amd64:
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.27).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.15.8).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgl1.
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.45.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.54.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 (>= 3.22.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpcre3.
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libpython2.7 (>= 2.7).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libsecret-1-0 (>= 0.7).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 7).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libtinfo5 (>= 6).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libuuid1 (>= 2.16).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libx11-6.
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libxml2 (>= 2.7.4).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on libzip4 (>= 0.10).
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0).

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.31.4-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community:amd64
```

So I attempted to fix the dependency problem after they were marked, using:

> sudo apt -f install

However this does not fix the dependency issues as expected. It just has be remove the application I previously installed entirely to fix the dependency conflict:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-base gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libdrm-etnaviv1 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libllvm6.0 libva-wayland2 libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7
  libxfconf-0-2 pimixer point-rpi rpi.gpio-common xfconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-workbench-community:amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 122 MB disk space will be freed.
```

All of the 64bit applications I have tried to install take me through this same perpetual cycle.

I also tried configuring the package after installing, but it gives me the same dependency errors.

I also checked to ensure that the dependency packages were actually installed with a suitable version for the application I was attempting to install... What am i missing?

Comment: `Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community:amd64.` looks like you're trying to install the `amd64` build of that package.  AMD64 is 64-bit x86, not 64-bit ARM.  You need to install the `arm64` package.  I don't know whether such a thing actually exists.  If it does, then presumably it will need a boatload of 64-bit libraries that are not yet installed on your system.  Using `sudo apt-get install ...` (not ``sudo apt install`) should get those libraries automatically.